# VB6 error 32797 using sizeform from a created dll, how to solve?

Tags: dll, vb6

I've got a dll with a public sub SysSetSizeDisp(eSize1, eSize2).
When i call this sub by an external project, systems return error 32797.
I've tryied to unregister and register my dll, to declare variable and then set "new statement".
does anybody know this problem?

here my function code:

```
Public Sub SysSetSizeDisp(eSmall As eBsDispSize, eBig As eBsDispSize)
Const STG_FUNC As String = "SysSetSizeDisp"

Dim fK As Single
Dim fRH As Integer
Dim fRW As Integer

    If eSmall > eBig Then Exit Sub

    If DpyCnf.WinSizeMax = SysDpyGetCurrentResolution() Then
        fRH = -H_TESTATA / Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
        fRW = -135 / Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Else
        fRH = 0
        fRW = 0
    End If

    Select Case eSmall
    Case Is = eDSize320x240
        fSCALA1W = 320 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA1H = 240 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize640x480
        fSCALA1W = 640 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA1H = 480 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize800x600
        fSCALA1W = 800 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA1H = 600 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize1024x768
        fSCALA1W = 1024 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA1H = 768 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize1152x864
        fSCALA1W = 1152 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA1H = 864 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize1280x960
        fSCALA1W = 1280 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA1H = 960 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize1280x1024
        fSCALA1W = 1280 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA1H = 1024 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize1600x1280
        fSCALA1W = 1600 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA1H = 1280 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    End Select

    Select Case eBig
    Case Is = eDSize320x240
        fSCALA2W = 320 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA2H = 240 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize640x480
        fSCALA2W = (640 + fRW) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA2H = (480 + fRH) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize800x600
        fSCALA2W = (800 + fRW) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA2H = (600 - fRH) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize1024x768
        fSCALA2W = (1024 + fRW) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA2H = (768 + fRH) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize1152x864
        fSCALA2W = (1152 + fRW) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA2H = (864 + fRH) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize1280x960
        fSCALA2W = (1280 + fRW) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA2H = (960 + fRH) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize1280x1024
        fSCALA2W = (1280 + fRW) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA2H = (1024 + fRH) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    Case Is = eDSize1600x1280
        fSCALA2W = (1600 + fRW) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
        fSCALA2H = (1280 + fRH) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    End Select

    fK = 9675 / 9600

    fSCALA1W = fSCALA1W * fK
    fSCALA1H = fSCALA1H * fK
    fSCALA2W = fSCALA2W * fK
    fSCALA2H = fSCALA2H * fK

    DpyCnf.WinSizeMin = eSmall
    DpyCnf.WinSizeMax = eBig

    Exit Sub
EH:
    Debug.Assert False
    cErr.MemoSave Err, STG_ME & "." & STG_FUNC
End Sub
```

Comment: what is DpyCnf,eBsDispSize and so forth? if SysSetSizeDisp a method of a form, class or in a public module? there is not enough information.

Comment: eBsDispSize is a enum, that's indicate screen size, dpyCnf is a type in which are defined  simple type variables and two enum eBsDispSize variable. All is in a public module

Comment: I've seen that is denied access to all dll's method, in class or in modules.

Comment: types can not be public in VB6, you have to use  class that you make public instead

Comment: type is defined now private in a module (where are defined different types). 
Function is developed in another module (with other screen's functions). 
In a class there's a wrapper for that function (is a very complicated architecture)  

`SysSetSizeDisp(sSmall as eBsDispSize, sBig as eBsDispSize)`

in this class(where is defined wrapper) there's public enum eBsDispSize.

Main project in main sub do this at first:
`Call SysSetSizeDisp (eSize1, eSize2)`

Comment: i don't think error comes from here, the only call that i suspect it generate the error is the call to SysDpyGetCurrentResolution()

Comment: No, beacuse this dll is used by other similar project. every project in main form, as first instruction, calls SysetSizeForm. 
Sometimes it makes mistake, 
if I create a vb6 group with principal project and ddl project, there's no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
i recompiled dll, cleaned registry,unregistered last version of dll and then re-registered it again (without modify dll source).
maybe some references were corrupted